# Why foreach is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, foreach

I am getting a `json` response from my server and I am trying to map it to an observable array and then to display the results inside of an `HTML` table. What I'm getting from the server is this string:

```
{"ids":[1,2,3,4],"names":["1","2","test tracker","test1"],"creators":["1","test","test","test"],"projectNames":["1","1","test project","test"]}
```

Now here is what I'm trying to do in my view model:

I have this object supposed to hold the values:

```
trackersObj = function(item){
         this.trackerId = item.ids;
         this.trackerName = item.names;
         this.trackerCreator = item.creators;
         this.projectNames = item.projectNames;
};
```

And this `ko.observableArray` supposed to hold the results and to loop trough it in the table's body:

```
trackersObjArray = ko.observableArray([])
```

And here is how I'm doing the mapping:

```
loadActiveTrackers = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'controller.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: "loadActiveTs"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            trackersObjArray.push(new trackersObj(data));
            console.log(trackersObjArray());
            $('#allTrackers').show();

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Something got wrong!');
        }
    });
};
```

Finally it's my `HTML`:

```
<table class="dataTable" id="CADataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: trackersObjArray">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="test" data-bind="value: trackerName">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that in the `tbody`'s `td` all the results are displayed in the same line.

Here is what I mean:

[image: Strange foreach issue]

It is supposed to create as many lines as the number of recoreds. Why is this happening? I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I know that I'm missing a super small part, but I'm not able to spot it at this momment.

**P.S.**

Here is the output of `console.log(trackersObjArray());`

[image: json structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server sends multiple objects, not a single one. It just does so in an unusual way:

```
{
    "ids": [1,2,3,4],
    "names": ["1","2","test tracker","test1"],
    "creators": ["1","test","test","test"],
    "projectNames": ["1","1","test project","test"]
}
```

really should look like this

```
[
   {"id": 1, "name": "1", "creator": "1", "projectName": "1"}, 
   {"id": 2, "name": "2", "creator": "test", "projectName": "1"}, 
   {"id": 3, "name": "test tracker", "creator": "test", "projectName": "test project"}, 
   {"id": 4, "name": "test1", "creator": "test", "projectName": "test"}
]
```

Consequently you must push your `trackersObj` objects in a loop. There are several options to to this.

First you must decide whether you want to

1. Update your server code to send a proper object structure right-away (preferred), or
2. leave the server as it is and transform the object on the client.

Since I don't see your server code, I'm going with option 2

```
loadActiveTrackers = function () {
    $.post('controller.php', {
        action: "loadActiveTs"
    }).then(function (rawData) {
        // transformation step. if you fix your server to send proper data
        // you can drop the entire then().
        var i, transformedData = [];

        for (i = 0; i < rawData.ids.length; i++) {
            transformedData.push({
                id: rawData.ids[i],
                name: rawData.namess[i],
                creator: rawData.creators[i],
                projectName: rawData.projectNames[i]
            });
        }

        return transformedData;
    }).done(function (transformedData) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(transformedData, function (tracker) {
            trackersObjArray.push(new trackersObj(tracker));
        });
    }).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Something got wrong!');
    });
};
```

This is the "manual" way. You could do without the for-each loop and instead replace the value of `trackersObjArray` in a single step (`trackersObjArray(transformedData);)`. You could also use the mapping plugin for more advanced data-to-viewmodel mappings.

---

You are not supposed to use jQuery in your view model (or otherwise refer to the DOM in any way) because this unnecessarily ties your view model to your view. The dependency ought to be the other way around only.

In other words, `$('#allTrackers').show();` should not be in the view model. Use the `visible` binding.

Comment: wow. I see. The problem is that I'm doing teh server side in `php` and I'm kinda of a niewbie in it. I have edit my question and placed the `php` code in there. Could you take a look? :)

Comment: Your PHP code is really easy to fix. Just look at my "how it should look like" JSON sample and think for a couple of minutes. You will figure it out on your own, I'm absolutely sure. (And it's gonna be more satisfying, too.)

Comment: @chility Oh, and one more thing: Unless you're actually *updating data* on the server (an it does't look like it), use `$.get()` instead of `$.post()`.